# Error al querer insertar productos en Woocommerce desde su API

Tags: api, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy usando Woocommerce y estoy queriendo añadir los productos de una API externa, sin embargo, se me presenta el siguiente error, el cual ya he probado todo lo que aparece en internet para resolver y nada que logro solucionar.

El error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
> Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: JSON ERROR:
> Syntax error in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api-woo-php\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php:411
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api-woo-php\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php(455):
> Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse() #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api-woo-php\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\Client.php(56): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('products',
> 'POST', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\api-woo-php\index.php(56):
> Automattic\WooCommerce\Client->post('products', Array) #3 {main}
> thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api-woo-php\vendor\automattic\woocommerce\src\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient.php
> on line 411

Mi codigo:

```
<?php

$consumer = "ck_db70e89c42c8d1f030931f6d3df479fd0905042e";
$consumerS = "cs_cb3133c55e053920b0707cf54ad3c420882788e7";


require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
  'https://delivery-app.tech/',
  $consumer,
  $consumerS,
  [
    // 'wp_api' => true,
    'version' => 'wc/v3',
    // 'query_string_auth' => true,
    // 'verify_ssl' => false,
  ]
);


$data = [
    'name' => 'Producto prueba',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '21.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
        ]
    ]
];


print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
```

Comment: supongo que ya revisaste la sintaxis del archivo JSON verdad?

Comment: Si, correcto. y todo esta perfecto.

Comment: en el wordpress donde está el api revisa enlaces permanentes (permalinks) dale guardar y si persiste pasale a la opcion predeterminada ( post-name ). hay ciertos casos en los que el parser de la url espera "url amigables" y al estar desconfigurado recibe un html en vez de un json. si tenes un cache/edge puede que necesites saltear/omitir la url del api. una prueba simple es poner la url en el navegador `view-source:https://delivery-app.tech/wp-json/wc/v3/orders` lo esperado es `{"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":401}}`

Comment: btw, el parseado correcto de la url sin permalinks es `https://delivery-app.tech/index.php?rest_route=/wc/v3/orders` si la libreria no lo resuelve seguramente haya un 404 que genera el syntax error de json